# Kibana not ready yet - OK ah why?

Tags: homebrew, kibana

UPDATE: I STILL CANNOT FIND THE STARTUP LOGS FOR KIBANA ANYWHERE.

I just installed Kibana after installing log stash on my Mac. I used brew install kabana.  Then I used brew install start service cabana. Then I see the error message Kibana not ready when I access on localhost:5601. Ok, so where do I go and find why Kibana is not ready yet? I dont see any logs for it under /var/logs.

So what I need is to know where to check the logs to see what is wrong. I have already checked that log stash is running on expected port. I have seen one other response and it was some cryptic reply that it could not find it under the service name logstash. Yet no mention anywhere of service names for install. Also can we have more useful information then Kibana not ready yet like Kibana not ready yet because it could not find X or Y.  Something that at least looks like its trying to help us during install. Who decides this kind of thing. Like we just see not ready yet with no mention of logs files or where they are located. Why not just startup and provide the start logs of Kabana? Would this not make more sense then just a meaningless message?

```
Steven$ brew services stop kibana
Stopping `kibana`... (might take a while)
==> Successfully stopped `kibana` (label: homebrew.mxcl.kibana)
coffee:log Steven$ brew services start kibana
==> Successfully started `kibana` (label: homebrew.mxcl.kibana)
```

I mean what a worthless error message. In fact its ambiguous as to whether there is an error at all. The absurdity is that a logging app and we are trying to hunt down the logs for this. Madness.

Comment: $ journalctl
-bash: journalctl: command not found

Comment: Also, Kibana takes some after starting Service. Check after a little while.

Comment: brew install journalctl
Error: No available formula with the name "journalctl"

Comment: As far as it taking a while to start the service is already up and nothing on earth should take more than 5 minutes to start in 2019

Comment: Are you using Mac?

Comment: YES, I AM USING A MAC.

Comment: Does Kibana not know where it is installed? Or where its log files are? Or if it had an error on install?  Will it be ready later, or did it run into an unrecoverable error.

Comment: It does not take that much time after start. docs says log location is  /usr/local/var/log/kibanapath.logs .. see this docs https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/kibana/current/brew.html

Comment: logstash log file is there but not kibana

Comment: Look installing using brew might not have been the best option but I should be able to find the logs for the startup somewhere right? And Kibana should not need logstash to give information on its own startup.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/199064/discussion-between-sandeep-patel-and-steven-smart).

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution reading this article:

https://logz.io/blog/elk-mac/

Looks like kibana file needs some updates before its ready. Not sure why that is not the message with a reference to the config file. Anyway still looking for kibana startup logs.  I dont see them anywhere.